# Essa pergunta é tão fora de escopo assim?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, sinalização

Pergunta em questão: [Como instalar o pip para uma determinada versão do Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/248677/64969)

O AP afirma ter instalado o Python, mas não consegui fazer algo com o `pip`, conflito de versão instalada com versão do `pip` disponível.

Fui ver a pergunta e imaginei:

> Puxa, alguém está tentando brincar com Python mas não está conseguindo

Depois de comentar, percebi que ela havia sido marcada como "fora de escopo -> não parece ser sobre programação".

Então, configurar o ambiente para programar ou *deployar* não é sobre programação? Claro, ele podia ser um usuário que está tentando rodar apenas um app Python em seu Ubuntu e que seria público alvo do SU, mas estou julgando primeiramente que ele tenha tido a boa intenção de perguntar sobre o ambiente de programação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu realmente me equivoquei ao escolher o motivo do fechamento, e concordo com isso, e peço desculpas pelo meu equívoco. Depois de analisar novamente a pergunta, eu percebi que ela não é fora de escopo.

Contudo, eu só havia ficado confuso sobre o problema do AP acerca do pip. Eu deveria ter votado como "não clara" pelo motivo de não ter compreendido qual seria o problema do AP em relação ao pip. Já que o pip esta atualmente na [versão 9.0.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/9.0.1), sendo que o AP disse que a versão 3 do pip no qual seria o pip3 é instalado automaticamente, mas, não existe esta versão do pip e ele não deu mais detalhes a respeito do problema. E a versão 9.0.1 funciona no Python 2 e 3.

Sendo assim, removi meu voto de fechamento e decidi não votar como "não clara", pois está me parecendo um mal entendimento a respeito das versões do pip e do Python.

Uma resposta poderia esclarecer essas dúvidas.

Comment: Diboas, @gato. Eu vi uma anomalia e achei que deveria mover terras e mares, para confirmar que foi fora do padrão ou para entender que eu quem estava fora. Espero sinceramente que o AP consiga sua desejada resposta

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado tranquilow. Ainda bem que vc postou aqui no meta, pq senão ia passar batido e a pergunta ia ser fechada rsrs

Comment: Eu já errei também, e continuo e**r**ando :D, faz parte

Answer (score 5):

Não é off-topic, pelo contrário é totalmente on-topic, ela fala sobre o `pip` e `python` em um ambiente especifico, ela se encaixa perfeitamente em:

> ferramentas comuns entre programadores

Conforme: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

O problema é que quem votou ali pra fechar não entende o escopo.

*E**r**ar* é humano, eu já errei também, o que nos cabe é orientar quando possível.