# Pergunta sobre Notepad++ é mesmo fora de escopo?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Sobre esta pergunta aqui: [Tecla de atalho para "surround with" no Notepad++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/287408/64969)

O AP põe uma dúvida bem clara:

- conheço um editor de texto com *feature* X
- será que esse outro editor também tem essa *feature*? Como usar?

Ambos os editores são comumente usados em programação, nominalmente:

- PhpStorm
- Notepad++

Como são ferramentas relacionadas a programação, estariam *on-topic*. Fontes:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
- https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6478/64969
- [Essa pergunta é tão fora de escopo assim?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6477/64969)
- a existência da tag [editor-de-texto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/editor-de-texto)
- a existência da tag [notepad++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b)

Sendo assim, não compreendo os votos de fechamento a esta pergunta. Parece-me ser dentro do tópico. E mesmo que a pergunta esteja mal-feita (outro motivo para "justificar" voto negativo), creio que ela poderia ser melhorada.

Comment: Neste momento existem somente dois votos para fechamento como insuficientemente clara, que de certa forma até concordo, pois não acho que a pergunta esteja em sua melhor forma. Haviam votos para fechar como fora do escopo?

Comment: Não, apenas 2, mas resolvi trazer a discussão logo à tona para evitar a frustração do fechamento para o novato. Pela velocidade em que eu vi a questão surgindo, seu primeiro voto de fechamento e o segundo, pensei que ela já estaria fechando quando eu tivesse terminado de escrever isto daqui. Mas pelo visto os votos de fechamento não tiveram o ímpeto/a inércia que eu previ. E também tinha 2 votos negativos juntos aos de fechamento, mas alguém removeu o negativo já

Comment: Nem eu entendo, parece ser coisa de caçador de medalha. Me avise se fechar para reabrir. A pergunta não é das melhores, mas não deve ser fechada a não ser por outro motivo que alguém me mostre que eu não percebi.

Comment: Eu havia visto a pergunta e a priori achei meio estranha e não fiz nada (fiquei na dúvida, embora tendesse a achar que a pergunta era válida, por isso não fiz nada). Ao acessar a fila de análises, a pergunta constou como "fora de escopo"... como eu estava na dúvida a princípio (acho que fui mais influenciado pelo conteúdo da pergunta do que pelo escopo), acompanhei o voto de fechamento e votei para fechar. Mas realmente ao chegar aqui acho que a pergunta é válida, e já cancelei meu voto.

Comment: É uma ferramenta de programação, não vejo sentido do porque calar alguém por isso

Comment: Acho que deveria continuar aberta. Poderíamos pensar na pergunta de um outra maneira como "No Notepad++, como reconhecer as tag da linguagem X", que me parece boa (linguagem, ferramenta, bom uso da ferramenta para desenvolver)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado poderia analisar minha pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211165/57801 . Já vi outras perguntas no site que não foram fechadas. Exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/112262/57801

Comment: @Everson concordo que parece ter um bom escopo. Inclusive creio que mereça uma resposta atualizada (uns 9 meses depois e ainda tá _só_ na promessa do PHPStorm suportar Hack?)

Comment: Ocorre que muitas perguntas não tem uma relação direta com um código ou programação e então os "super empoderados do site" julgam como fora do escopo, subjugando a dúvida e até mesmo o usuário que a postou.

Comment: Por que dizes isso? Tem algum ponto em específico que queira discutir? Eu trouxe essa pergunta para alertar um comportamento que julguei ser fora do normal, inclusive apontando o porquê era fora do normal. Isso foi reconhecido pela comunidade, numa espécie de retroalimentação de controle, fazendo então a questão ter o destino digno antes de ser fechada.

Comment: Sim, já tive o desprazer de ver minha humilde pergunta rejeitada só porque queria saber qual software usar para desenvolver. Eu acreditei que estaria fazendo a pergunta no melhor lugar. Ou seja, tem uma relação indireta com a programação em si.

Comment: do jeito que você descreveu, ela é baseada em opinião e não é lá muito objetiva. Está fora do contexto do Stack Overflow, parece mais algo que deveria ser perguntado no Quora

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eu não me preocuparia muito com isso. As vezes alguém com o poder de voto pode ter dúvidas sobre o escopo de uma pergunta, ou uma má interpretação. Acontece. Mas tudo aqui é feito por consenso. Por isso que são necessários cinco votos para fechar ;)

Mesmo que o primeiro voto influencie os demais, e que uma pergunta boa seja fechada, nós sempre podemos vir ao meta e discutir o mérito da publicação. Se for uma boa pergunta, ela pode ser reaberta.

---

No caso da pergunta específica, eu acho que ela é muito boa. Ela vai direto ao tema e muita gente tem o mesmo problema. Deixei uma resposta wiki lá, para estimular a participação de mais gente. Se amanhã ela estiver aberta, mas com mais votos para fechar, eu abro uma recompensa e grito "TRUCO" na cara dos fechadores.